# Prevent Input of previous Date with date_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there an option with the Rails 4 FormTagHelper **date_field_tag** which allows me to prevent users from selecting a date previous to the current?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, checking the documentation the sintax for date_field_tag is the following:

datetime_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})

The options accepts arguments such as (:min, :max)

Im not fond of Rails4, but you could probably declare a variable that holds the current day date and then pass it as a value for the ':min' argument, something like:

```
datetime_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {:min=> @todayvariable})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I thing to add is the date string needs to be formatted yyyy-mm-dd.  Of course when researching this, I found out the input type isn't support in FF or IE yet...