# Prevent users from selecting passed date with date_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to make `date_field_tag` prevent users from selecting a date previous to the current?

I'm looking to implement it here in a haml form:

`= date_field_tag 'portal[email][launch_date]', (@email_params[:launch_date] if @email_params)`

I am not sure how to fit it here. Or, is there another alternative to using date_field_tag?

Answer (score 1):

Need to pass min in options

```
datetime_field_tag('portal[email][launch_date]',@email_params[:launch_date],{:min=> Date.today})
```

[Prevent Input of previous Date with date_field_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194298/prevent-input-of-previous-date-with-date-field-tag/21194439)